# Concept Question on calling values in nested dictionaries for Python3

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have to figure out a way to find the sum total of certain values in nested dictionaries first with a for loop and then within a single line using the sum function and dictionary comprehension.

I CANNOT assume that the dictionaries are ordered nor are they the same size, but I can assume that the TARGET key:value pair for each nest has the same Key name. Here is a mock example dictionary:

```
dict1 = { "key 1" :
                { "key1a" : "abcde",
                "key_b_name" : 6, #take this value and add it to a running total
                "key1c" : [list1]},
            "key 2" :
                { "key2a" : "abcde",
                "key_b_name" : 32, #take this value and add it to a running total
                "key2c" : [list2]}
             ...
            }
```

My for loop should run through any additional dictionaries that would come up. What would be a naive way of solving this?

My thought process for the for loop would first be to set a variable called running_total = 0 and then I want the for_loop to go through each dictionary in dict1 and `running total += dict1[key_b_name"]` and then finally print the running total. Am I missing an index to call a nested dictionary if I follow this method, if so, what's the syntax.

Then I'm still trying to get the hang of list/dict comprehension so I need to understand how to replace the for loop with one line of code which uses the sum function.

Comment: The maximum nesting depth is one?

Comment: Yes, there is the overarching dict1, and then it has nested dictionaries, but nothing further than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [11]: dict1
Out[11]:
{'key 1': {'key1a': 'abcde', 'key1b': 6, 'key1c': ['a']},
 'key 2': {'key2a': 'abcde', 'key2b': 32, 'key2c': ['c']}}

In [12]: sum(v[i] for k,v in dict1.items() for i in v if i.startswith("key") and i.endswith("b"))
Out[12]: 38
```

Update:
As the key name stays constant,

```
In [17]: dict1
Out[17]:
{'key 1': {'key1a': 'abcde', 'key_b_name': 6, 'key1c': ['a']},
 'key 2': {'key2a': 'abcde', 'key_b_name': 32, 'key2c': ['a']}}

In [18]: sum(v[i] for k,v in dict1.items() for i in v if i == "key_b_name")
Out[18]: 38
```

Comment: This is a pretty interesting approach, but the only issue is that I'm not sure if the keys actually start with "key" nor end with "b". It was more of a mock up dictionary of the concept so I could learn the method. I'm still trying to wrap my head around list/dict comprehension too.

Comment: @snicksnackpaddywhack91 if you don't know what the keys are, how can you possibly know which to use? You said: `I want to get the totals of all the key<?>b values`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah that was the problem I was having. The prompt in question only had the full first dictionary with 5 key:value pairs, and then just gave me a "..." and told me to write a line of code to find all the totals of the implied dictionaries. I believe it is intended as more of a concept question which should work in all cases.
Edit: "I want to get the totals of all the key<?>b values" I meant to imply that I wanted to get the totals for each of those values at those key locations. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: @MarkMeyer, I reached out to my TA and my assumptions about the dictionary were wrong (I assumed order and size were constant) but the only thing I can assume is constant is that the specific key:value pair I was looking at will be the same across each nested dictionary. He recommended I look at the expanded for loop first and then try again with the list comprehension. Any tips on how to tackle that?

Comment: So, what keys are you looking at?

Comment: So all the b-keys will have the same name in each nested dictionary. Lets' call them all 
"key_b_name"  so maybe I wont need to use "startwith/endswith" but maybe something else. Maybe just "is"?

Comment: @snicksnackpaddywhack91 I would encourage to edit the question and put the exact requirement there as required in the assignment

Comment: I've reworked my post as best I can to be as clear as possible. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = { "key 1" :
                { "key1a" : "abcde",
                "key1b" : 6,
                "key1c" : ''},
            "key 2" :
                { "key2a" : "abcde",
                "key2b" : 32,
                "key2c" : ''}
        }

tot = [list(i.values())[1] for i in dict1.values()]
print(sum(tot))
```

Output :

```
38
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python, but I think I was told that I couldn't use index values with dictionary key names. Eg I had to call the key names ["key1b"] for each key name. It would be much easier if I could use index numbers, which I'm assuming you're telling me I can?

Comment: i can use index, because first i take only the values, then i convert them into a list. If you new to Python then you learn about dictionary, you should learn about keys() and values()

Comment: Ah! I see! I didn't pay attention to the brackets outside the line of code! So does that mean I understood correctly- That I can't call index locations with dictionaries? Edit: I'm really not paying attention tonight, sorry, you even used the list command. I think this solution should work across all cases. Thanks so much for the explaination!

Comment: You cannot use the index of dictionary directly, even you only take the keys or values. For example : `some_dictonary.values()[0]` this still error. You need to convert them into list. The correct : `list(some_dictonary.values())[0]`

Comment: I just reached out to my TA and it seems that my assumptions were incorrect. The order and sizes of the nested dictionary is not constant/can not be assumed. But we can assume that the key:value pair will be the same across each dictionary. I guess I need to rework this one with both a for-loop and then the list comprehension shorthand.